# OpenCl installation on Ubuntu Gnome 16.10

Tags: opencl

I'm trying to build a software from source, OpenCL is a required package. But I'm really confused as to what it is and how to install it.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCL is a framework for parallel computing on GPUs and multi-core CPUs. To use it, you need to install a platform, which may depend on what kind of hardware you have, and what type of device your application wants to use. Here is a list of the main platforms:

- AMD APP: for AMD GPUs and Intel/AMD CPUs http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/
- NVIDIA CUDA: for NVIDIA GPUs only https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads
- Intel: for Intel CPUs https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-opencl